# Unable to send OSC messages with node's osc package. Port closed error, even though the port on the machine is open

Tags: node.js, osc

I'm using the code below to try send OSC messages to a computer on the network. I'm using a package called [osc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/osc).

I'm unable to send messages to the machine running the OSC server and receive the error below when attempting to send OSC messages:

```
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Can't send packets on a closed osc.Port object. Please open (or reopen) this Port by calling open().)
```

**Code**

```
let osc = require('osc');

let oscUDP = new osc.UDPPort({
    remoteAddress: "192.168.1.5",
    remotePort: 8004
});

oscUDP.send({
    address: "/carrier/frequency",
    args: 440
});

oscUDP.open();
```

If I put `oscUDP.open()` before the `send` call I get a different error:

```
Error: send EINVAL 192.168.1.5:8004
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1030:20)
at SendWrap.afterSend [as oncomplete] (dgram.js:402:11)
```

I am running OSCulator on OSX as the server. The code above lives on a different machine. When I run `nmap` on the IP address the port is open:

```
nmap 192.168.1.5 -p 8004

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-30 08:22 BST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8004/tcp open unknown
```

If I use [osc-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/osc-cli) the messages are received on the machine running the OSC server:

```
osc --host 192.168.1.5:8004 /test 1 2 3
```

So it would seem the problem isn't with closed ports at all as the messages are sent and received when using osc-cli.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm coming to this quite late, and it looks like you found a different library that works for you, but I thought a response might be helpful for others who are facing this issue. I'm the developer of osc.js, the original library you were trying to use.

First off, as background information, osc.js is factored into two different layers:

1. The low-level API that provides functions for reading and writing OSC messages and bundles to/from Typed Arrays.
2. The higher-level, event-based Port API, which provides a collection of platform-specific transport objects, which offer an easy way to do bidirectional communication over protocols like UDP, Web Sockets, etc.

In the case of your example code, you were trying to send an OSC message on your `UDPPort` object prior to it being ready. When you `open()` a `Port`, it may need to perform asynchronous operations such as opening up a socket, etc. As a result, it fires an event (aptly called `ready`) when the Port is all set to be used. Until `ready` fires, you won't be able to send or receive OSC packets.

So in the case of your original code, it looks like you were assuming that this line was synchronous and that you could call `send()` immediately afterwards:

```
oscUDP.open();
```

Instead, you just needed to listen for the `ready` event prior to attempting to send a message on the `Port`. Like this:

```
oscUDP.on("ready", function () {
    oscUDP.send({
        address: "/carrier/frequency",
        args: 440
    });
});
```

The [osc.js Node.js example](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js-examples/blob/master/nodejs/index.js) illustrates this pattern. But when I saw your question, I realized that the sample code in the osc.js README was a bit ambiguous in this regard. I have [improved the event documentation](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js/#events) and [the inline README sample code](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js/#sending-osc-messages) to be more clear in this regard. Sorry for the confusion.

There are cases, perhaps such as yours, where the higher-level API isn't quite what you need. osc.js also provides functions for easily encoding an OSC packet as a `Uint8Array`, which can be converted into a Node.js buffers. So you could have done something similar to your solution just by using osc.js' `osc.writeMessage()` function. It has always been quite well documented, fortunately. Here's your example, modified to use osc.js' low-level API:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const osc = require('osc');

const HOST = '192.168.1.5';
const PORT = 8004;

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  client.close();
});

let oscNoteMessage = function(note, value) {
  var message = osc.writeMessage({
      address: '/note/' + note,
      args: [
          {
              type: 'i',
              value: value
          }
      ]
    });

  return Buffer.from(message);
}

let noteOn = function(note) {
  return oscNoteMessage(note, 1);
}

let noteOff = function(note) {
  return oscNoteMessage(note, 0);
}

let send = function(message) {
  client.send(message, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);
  })
}

send(noteOn('c'));
setTimeout(function() {
  send(noteOff('c'));
}, 1000);
```

Anyway, I'm glad you were able to come up with a solution that works for your project, and I hope this response helps other users who may encounter similar issues. And of course, feel free to ask questions or file issues on the [osc.js issue tracker](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js/issues).

Best regards, and apologies for the trouble you experienced using the library!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it's actually pretty easy to send OSC data over UDP without the need for any packages except `a2r-osc` which is used for encoding OSC data.

I'm posting the solution incase anyone else in interested:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const osc = require('a2r-osc');

const HOST = '192.168.1.5';
const PORT = 8004;

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  client.close();
});

let noteOn = function(note) {
  return new osc.Message('/note/' + note, 'i', 1).toBuffer();
}

let noteOff = function(note) {
  return new osc.Message('/note/' + note, 'i', 0).toBuffer();
}

let send = function(message) {
  client.send(message, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);
  })
}

send(noteOn('c'));
setTimeout(function() {
  send(noteOff('c'));
}, 1000);
```